# How to make text in a UITableViewCell wordwrap?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView with a few sections. The text in some of the cells can get quite long, I was wondering how I could make the text word-wrap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

eg

```
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

You can set this to a fixed number of lines if you prefer.  It may be a good idea to set the lineBreakMode, and you will probably need to implement:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

using:

```
NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll have the specify the number of lines the text will use. 
Setting it to zero will wrap it automatically.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0; // line wrap
```

Answer (score 2):

set numberOfLines > 1 on your label and set an appropriate lineBreakMode as well. You might need to modify the frame of the label to have enough space. You can do this in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: of your table view delegate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this question [Custom Cell Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494562/setting-custom-uitableviewcells-height), right? I don't really get what word-wrap do, but I assume that you want to change the cell size according to the text length, is that right? So you can look at the above question and answer

Comment: Setting the cell height larger does not make the text fit. It still presents the "..." to the truncated text.

Comment: "There is one label in the cell whose text is a NSString object and the length of string could be variable , due to this i cannot set a constant height to the cell in UITableViews : heightForCellAtIndex method. " (copied from the question), how about putting it into some UILabel and try again?

Comment: If I set the label property on the cell I can make it wordwrap. If the frame of the label exceeds the size of the cell, then I need to define a custom cell height. I guess both changes need to be made :)