# How to increase the height of custom cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a tableview that fill with custom cells,, Now I want to increase the width of the cell,I increased the cell height of UITableview. But the problem is still same. Any one know how to increase the height of custom cell in UITableView.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cell heights vary, implement the following delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0; // edit this return value to your liking
}
```

If they don't, merely set the `rowHeight` property of your table view instance to whatever height you want all of your cells to be. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730427/347339) does a good job of explaining why.