# UIButton: calculate height of UIButton based on titleLabel Text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel

I have a custom UIButton in a custom UITableViewCell. I want to set the height of the UIButton in the custom table cell based on the variable textual content of the titleLabel of the button.

I tried the following method to calculate the height

```
[NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:];
```

but I could not successfully change the button height as per the titleLabel.

Further, as this button is part of a custom UITableViewCell, I also need to change the height of the cell as per the height of the custom UIButton.

In the ViewController implementing the delegate and the datasource methods of the UITableView, I tried to determine the height in the following method

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but was not successful.

What could be the best solution or approach to solve this?

Comment: See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506313/dynamic-size-of-uitablecell-hight/12506358#12506358

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the width of your button is 145.0f:

```
CGSize constraintSize;

constraintSize.width = 145.0f;

constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;

CGSize size = [Label.text sizeWithFont:Label.font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Then you can set the frame:

```
frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, size.height);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you do it right, but remember:

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` must return `CGFloat`
`sizeWithFont` gives you height of text, you need to add padding of your button, and cell

use `constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(###,MAXFLOAT)` where ### is your text width

`lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap` of course

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `[buttonInstance sizeToFit]`.

```
 UIButton *lineButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 // If padding equals "yes, please"
 [lineButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f)];
 [lineButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [lineButton sizeToFit];
```