# UITableView cell height for iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to adapt the height of the cells of a UITableView in swift programmatically for iOS 7.1.2 (sadly got asked for it.). There are no issues for all iOS versions after 7 but as it is the UITableView displays with a height of 1..

Here is my code (I made the interface programmatically as I literally HATE the design interface of Xcode and don't use AutoLayout).
Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot missed UITableView]

```
import UIKit

class ChemieListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate  {

private var imageView = UIImageView ()
private var bg_image = UIImage()
private var titre = UILabel()
private var button_Back = UIButton()
var navigationBar = UIView()
var items:[String] =  ["1","A","B","C","D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

var lbl_suche_by_txt = UILabel()
var text_search = UITextField()
var alph_list = UITableView()
var lbl_such_by_alph = UILabel()
var scroll: UIScrollView!
var scroll_h: CGFloat =  CGFloat(0)
private var waitView = UIView()
private var loading_view = UIImageView()
private var loading_text = UILabel()
private var has_started = false
private var bg_infro = UIView()
private var txt_info = UILabel()
private var options_pics = UIImageView()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //---------------------Scroll View-----------------------------
    self.scroll = UIScrollView()
    scroll_h = 0
    //----------------------Wait screen---------------------------
    waitView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    waitView.alpha = 0.8
    let ScreenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    loading_text.text = NSLocalizedString("wait", comment: " ")
    loading_text.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
    loading_text.textAlignment = .Center
    loading_text.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)

    //----------------------Navigation Bar-------------------------
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = GetColorFromHex(0x2139D2)
    //----------------------Back Button----------------------------
    var back_img: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "back")
    if (back_img == nil){
        back_img = UIImage(named: "back.png")
    }
    button_Back.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button_Back.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProduktViewController.button_back_Pressed), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    button_Back.setBackgroundImage(back_img, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button_Back.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(button_Back)
    //----------------------Background Image-----------------------
    //Background Image
    var BGImage: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "background")
    if(BGImage == nil){
        BGImage = UIImage(named: "background.jpg")
    }
    bg_image = BGImage!
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    imageView.image = bg_image
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
    //------------------------Title------------------------------------
    let largeur_title = ScreenSize.width - button_Back.frame.width - 30
    titre.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    titre.text = NSLocalizedString("liste", comment: " ")
    titre.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    titre.frame = CGRect (x: button_Back.frame.origin.x + button_Back.frame.width + 10, y: button_Back.frame.origin.y, width: largeur_title, height: 50)
    titre.textAlignment = .Center
    //---------------------txt For input search-----------------------
    lbl_suche_by_txt.text = NSLocalizedString("search_field", comment: "")
    lbl_suche_by_txt.textAlignment = .Center
    lbl_suche_by_txt.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    //---------------------TextField input---------------------------
    text_search.delegate = self
    text_search.resignFirstResponder()
    text_search.textAlignment = .Center
    text_search.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    text_search.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("search_here", comment: "")
    text_search.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    text_search.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    //---------------------txt For alphabetical search-----------------------
    lbl_such_by_alph.text = NSLocalizedString("search_list", comment: "")
    lbl_such_by_alph.textAlignment = .Center
    lbl_such_by_alph.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    //---------------------Table View Alphabet-------------------------------
    alph_list.delegate = self
    alph_list.dataSource = self
    alph_list.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    alph_list.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
    alph_list.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    //---------------------BG Info Rights------------------------------------
    bg_infro.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    txt_info.text = NSLocalizedString("rights", comment: "")
    txt_info.numberOfLines = 0
    txt_info.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()


    let orient = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
    switch orient{
    case .Portrait:
        self.setContstraintsPortrait()
        break
    default:
        self.setContstraintsLandscape()
        break
    }

    navigationBar.addSubview(button_Back)
    navigationBar.addSubview(titre)
    self.scroll.addSubview(lbl_suche_by_txt)
    self.scroll.addSubview(text_search)
    self.scroll.addSubview(lbl_such_by_alph)
    self.scroll.addSubview(alph_list)
    self.scroll.addSubview(bg_infro)
    self.scroll.addSubview(txt_info)
    waitView.addSubview(loading_text)
    waitView.hidden = true
    self.scroll.addSubview(waitView)
    self.view.addSubview(scroll)
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)


}




override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    alph_list.reloadData()
    var table_height:CGFloat = 0
    //----------------Init Values----------------------
    let ScreenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let w = ScreenSize.width

        for index in 0...items.count - 1 {
            let IndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:index, inSection:0)
            let cell = alph_list.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath)
            if cell != nil {
                let cell: UITableViewCell = alph_list.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath)!
                cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
                cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
                print(cell.textLabel?.text)
                alph_list.endUpdates()
                table_height += alph_list.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath)!.frame.height
                print(table_height)
                if #available(iOS 8, *){
                    table_height += alph_list.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath)!.frame.height
                }else{
                    print(table_height)
                }
            }
        }
    alph_list.frame =  CGRect (x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: lbl_such_by_alph.frame.origin.y + lbl_such_by_alph.frame.height + 10, width: w - 20 , height: 26*45)
    alph_list.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200, (26*45))
    //-------------BG info rights--------------------------
    bg_infro.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: alph_list.frame.origin.y + alph_list.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: 220)
    //-------------BG txt rights--------------------------
    txt_info.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x + 10, y: bg_infro.frame.origin.y + 10  , width: w - 40, height: 250)
    scroll_h = bg_infro.frame.origin.y + bg_infro.frame.height + 30
    self.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w, scroll_h)
    has_started = true
}


func setContstraintsLandscape(){

    print("portrait func beständigkeitsliste")
    //----------------Scroll View-----------------------
    scroll.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    //----------------Init Values-----------------------
    let ScreenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let w = ScreenSize.width
    let h = ScreenSize.height
    let zero: CGFloat = 0

    //-------------Background---------------------------
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(zero,zero, w, h)
    imageView.image = bg_image
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
    //---------------Navigation Bar--------------------
    navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: 60)
    //--------------Button Back-------------------------
    button_Back.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    button_Back.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)
    //--------------Title-------------------------------
    titre.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: button_Back.frame.origin.y, width: w, height: 50)
    //-------------Text Search by Text------------------
    lbl_suche_by_txt.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: button_Back.frame.origin.y + button_Back.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: 40)
    //-------------Text Field Search by Text------------------
    text_search.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: lbl_suche_by_txt.frame.origin.y + lbl_suche_by_txt.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: 40)
    //-------------Text Search by Alphabet------------------
    lbl_such_by_alph.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: text_search.frame.origin.y + text_search.frame.height + 30 , width: w - 20, height: 40)
    //-------------List Alphabet------------------
    var table_height: CGFloat = 0
    if(has_started == false){
        table_height = CGFloat(items.count * 50)
    }else{
        for index in 0...items.count - 1 {
            let IndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:index, inSection:0)
            let cell = alph_list.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath)
            if cell != nil {
                table_height += alph_list.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath)!.frame.height
            }
        }
    }
    alph_list.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: lbl_such_by_alph.frame.origin.y + lbl_such_by_alph.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: table_height)
    //-------------BG info rights--------------------------
    bg_infro.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: alph_list.frame.origin.y + alph_list.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: 220)
    //-------------BG txt rights--------------------------
    txt_info.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x + 10, y: bg_infro.frame.origin.y + 20 , width: w - 40, height: 250)



    //-------------Scroll View Size-------------------------------
    scroll_h = alph_list.frame.origin.y + table_height + 30
    self.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(ScreenSize.width, scroll_h)
    //----------------Wait Screen-----------------------
    waitView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.scroll.frame.height)
    loading_text.frame = CGRect(x: (ScreenSize.width - 150) / 2, y: (ScreenSize.height - 100) / 2, width: 150, height: 100)


}

func setContstraintsPortrait(){

    print("portrait func liste chemie")
    //----------------Scroll View-----------------------
    scroll.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    //----------------Init Values-----------------------
    let ScreenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let w = ScreenSize.width
    let h = ScreenSize.height
    let zero: CGFloat = 0

    //--------------------------------------------------
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(zero,zero, w, h)
    imageView.image = bg_image
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
    //---------------Navigation Bar---------------------
    navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: 80)
    //--------------Button Back-------------------------
    button_Back.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    button_Back.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 50, 50)
    //--------------Title-------------------------------
    titre.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: button_Back.frame.origin.y, width: w, height: 50)
    //-------------Text Search by Text------------------
    lbl_suche_by_txt.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: button_Back.frame.origin.y + button_Back.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: 40)
    //-------------Text Field Search by Text------------------
    text_search.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: lbl_suche_by_txt.frame.origin.y + lbl_suche_by_txt.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: 40)
    //-------------Text Search by Alphabet------------------
    lbl_such_by_alph.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: text_search.frame.origin.y + text_search.frame.height + 30 , width: w - 20, height: 40)
    //-------------List Alphabet------------------
    var table_height: CGFloat = 0
    if(has_started == false){
        table_height = CGFloat(items.count * 50)
    }else{
        for index in 0...items.count - 1 {
            let IndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:index, inSection:0)
            let cell = alph_list.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath)
            if cell != nil {
                table_height += alph_list.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath)!.frame.height
            }
        }
    }
    alph_list.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: lbl_such_by_alph.frame.origin.y + lbl_such_by_alph.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: table_height)
    alph_list.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w-20, table_height)

    print(table_height)

    //-------------BG info rights--------------------------
    bg_infro.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x, y: alph_list.frame.origin.y + alph_list.frame.height + 10 , width: w - 20, height: 220)
    //-------------BG txt rights--------------------------
    txt_info.frame = CGRect(x: button_Back.frame.origin.x + 10, y: bg_infro.frame.origin.y + 20  , width: w - 40, height: 250)
    //-------------Scroll View Size-------------------------------
    scroll_h = alph_list.frame.origin.y + table_height + 30
    self.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w, scroll_h)
    //----------------Wait Screen-----------------------
    waitView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.scroll.frame.height)
    loading_text.frame = CGRect(x: (w - 150) / 2, y: (h - 100) / 2, width: 150, height: 100)

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    text_search.resignFirstResponder()
    print("Oki")
    let listresultview: ListResultsViewController = ListResultsViewController(imageURL: text_search.text)
    self.presentViewController(listresultview, animated:true, completion: nil)

    return true
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.items.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    waitView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scroll.bounds.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.scroll.frame.height)
    loading_text.frame = CGRect(x: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 150) / 2, y: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 100) / 2, width: 150, height: 100)
    self.waitView.hidden = false
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.loadListResultView(indexPath.row)
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    text_search.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom UITableViewCell.
Adding the constraints to UITableViewCell contentView resolved it for me.

Comment: How do you add Constraints programmatically? (I tried the programmatically way to avoid Constraints but if it's the only way sure I will do it..)

Comment: I suggest to create a custom UITableViewCell

Comment: Any links to how to make derived uiclasses? I'm not so familiar with the principe.

Comment: You can start from this post (great job)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25433668/2759924
And also this is good (short tutorial):
http://blog.luduscella.com/uitableview/how-to-implement-uitableview-programmatically-using-swift