# UITableview scrolling is not responding properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift4

```
 booktable.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: booktopview.bounds.height, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight-booktopview.bounds.height-tabbarView.bounds.height)

            booktable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycell")
            booktable.dataSource = self
            booktable.delegate = self
            booktable.separatorColor = UIColor.lightGray
            booktable.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            booktable.separatorStyle = .singleLine

            bookview.addSubview(booktable)



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if(tableView == booktable)
    {
     let cell1 = booktable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell")

        for object in (cell1?.contentView.subviews)!
        {
            object.removeFromSuperview();
        }

        let img :UIImageView = UIImageView()
        let lbl : UILabel = UILabel()


        img.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: 80, height: 130)
        img.image = imgarray[indexPath.row]
        img.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        img.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell1?.contentView.addSubview(img)

        imgheight = img.bounds.height

        lbl.frame = CGRect(x: img.bounds.width + 40, y: (imgheight+40-80)/2, width: booktable.bounds.width-img.bounds.width + 40 - 100, height: 80)
        lbl.text = imgname[indexPath.row]
        lbl.numberOfLines = 0

        lbl.textAlignment = .left
        lbl.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 23)
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.black
         cell1?.selectionStyle = .none



        cell1?.contentView.addSubview(lbl)

        return cell1!
    }
```

The code shown above is for book table, which sometimes scrolls like normal and sometimes not scrolling at all. I am doing all the code programatically. I have tested this on both simulators and devices but still the problem exists. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: for object in (cell1?.contentView.subviews)!
        {
            object.removeFromSuperview();
        } this is the reason

Comment: i am have multiple tableviews so if i dont use it the contents are overlaping,wat should i do about it?

Comment: You should create custom UITableViewCell

Comment: could u help me with a sample code

Comment: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Custom `UITableViewCell`, let's say it is `ListTableCell`

```
class ListTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTemp: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgTemp: UIImage!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

I've created `UITableViewCell` with `xib` like this and bind `IBOutlets`

[image]

Let's say we have `struct Model` and `array` like this

```
struct Model {
    let image : UIImage
    let name: String
}

for i in 0...10 {
    let model = Model(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cat03"), name: "Temp \(i)")
    array.append(model)
}
```

Now on `ViewController` `viewDidLoad()` method,

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ListTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListTableCell")
```

Implement `UITableViewDataSource` methods like this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListTableCell") as! ListTableCell
    let model = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblTemp.text = model.name
    cell.imgTemp.image = model.image        
    return cell
}
```

**FYI**

For different tableviews, you can create different custom cell the same way and `cellForRowAt indexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` method will change appropriately.

Let me know in case of any queries.

**UPDATE**

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413239/custom-uitableviewcell-programmatically-using-swift) and [this](http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2015/09/uitableviewcell-create-custom-prototype.html) to create CustomTableCell programmatically

Comment: is there  a way to not use xib's or storyboard?

Comment: yup you can create your customcell programmatically also

Comment: i was trying to do that way and then the contends of tableview ovelaps, so i used the code for object in (cell1?.contentView.subviews)!
        {
            object.removeFromSuperview();
        }         it solved the issue in all 3 tableviews but scrolling issue popped on booktable only

Comment: see my updated answer, there are links to create cell programmatically

Comment: You should extend UITableViewCell and on init method, you can addsubview to cell's contentview, no need to remove all subviews then because it will reuse the customcell itself