# Swift - Custom textLabel in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

at the moment I have a `UITableView` where the user can add `cells` that have a `textLabel` inside of it.

That is how I set the `label`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath)
    let currentWish = self.wishList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentWish.wishName
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear

    return cell
}
```

My question is, how I can custom `textLabel` (font, constraints,...). I tried creating a custom `UILabel` inside my `WishCell` class but I can not access it in `cellforRowAt` with `cell.theLabel`.

I hope you understand my problem, I am very grateful for every help :)

***SOLVED***

I just forgot the `as! WhishCell` in `cellForRowAt`. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: yes, I am doing that. But my problem is that I need to custom `textLabel` and I don't know how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UITableViewCell programmatically using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413239/custom-uitableviewcell-programmatically-using-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast to you cell custom class name

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! CellName
cell.lbl.text = ////
```

---

```
 class CellName:UITableViewCell {
    let lbl = UILabel() 
   override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) 
       lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
       self.contentView.addSubview(lbl)
       // set constraints here 
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
 }
```

Comment: you can change the font but not constraints , you need to do this with `lbl` in your custom cell

Comment: any way I can create a `customLabel` inside my `Class WhishCell`  so I can call `cell.customLabel.text = currentWish.wishName` inside `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: aaah I was just an idiot... I missed the `as! WhishCell` ! Thanks man :D

Answer (score 0):

Dont force un-wrap it.. try using `guard` or `if let`

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? WhishCell else{
  return UITableViewCell()
}
cell.lbl.text = "my text" 
let currentWish = self.wishList[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = currentWish.wishName
cell.backgroundColor = .clear

return cell
```