# Can't change UITableViewCell contentView height

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I have a custom `uitableviewcell`.

i want to change its height based on some if condition.
How can i be able to do this ?

I tried doing this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  -

```
if (cell.newsFeedImage.image == NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"NULL");
    cell.uDisplayImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
}
```

The log message appears, but the frame never changes.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting custom UITableViewCells height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494562/setting-custom-uitableviewcells-height)

Answer (score 1):

try to do this in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    CustomCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.newsFeedImage.image == nil) {
        cell.uDisplayImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
    } 
    else return 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of the cell is set in the tableView datasource method

heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I know that,

but i also want to reduce the height of content view inside uitableviecell

Comment: This method is part of the delegate protocol. You don't use it to set the height, you return the height from it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complicated than that.

This questions has been answered at great length here: [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)