# How to make a UITableViewCell longer in height?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview

My app has a `UITableViewController`. I want to show an image in the first section and add some other cells in another section. Like this:

```
-------
|     |   <--- image
|     |
-------

blah blah blah   <--- some other cells
--------------
blah blah blah
--------------
blah blah blah
```

And I thought it is as easy as this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == irrelevant {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let image = UIImageView(image: someImage, highlightedImage: nil)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(image)
        return cell
    }
    // Code for the other cells, irrelevant
}
```

But it came out like this:

[image]

As you can see, the image is out of the cell! What I want to do is to stretch the cell so that the image is actually "inside" the cell. I tried this:

```
cell.sizeToFit()
```

and this:

```
cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.width, image.frame.height + 15)
```

but both didn't work (The result stays the same)!

Is there a way to stretch it? If there isn't, how can I display an image in a `UITableViewController`?

Note: Don't tell me to set the `imageView` property of the cell. It's too small!

Comment: Use tableView delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: change cell height in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: With this example you alwais can put all elements and cell always get nice height and tableview too:http://stackoverflow.com/a/35022751/4693765. Put reload when change values of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

 if indexPath.section == 0 {
   return heightForYourImage
  }
  else if indexPath.section == 1 {
    return heightForYour labels
  }

}
```