# UITableview screen disturbed on iPhone 6plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iphone-6-plus

I've been facing an issue only on iPhone 6plus (my app is Universal), My tableview rows height show lesser than which I defined (almost 2 to 3 pixels). I solved this issue by adding tableview constraint via programmatically like following code.

```
NSInteger deviceSize = [SDVersion deviceSize];
if (deviceSize == Screen5Dot5inch) {
    [self.tableViewLoginFields setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableViewLoginFields.frame.origin.x, self.tableViewLoginFields.frame.origin.y, self.tableViewLoginFields.frame.size.width, 88)];
    self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 88;
}
```

The property `tableViewHeightConstraint` is height constraints and hooked up like `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableViewHeightConstraint;`. Row height is equal to 44 and here 2 rows are in table view. This worked fine but I have used around 20 `UITableview` and app constantly growing with passage of time so I am looking for some better solution.

I also added all splash according with all compatible devices so no issue with splash. I want to know that is this Apple end issue or somebody also faced and fixed this. Looking for answers. Thanks.

Comment: could yours be a repeat [of a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494562/setting-custom-uitableviewcells-height) ?

Comment: @aug2uag Please read carefully both questions before posting this comment.

Comment: did you say `My tableview rows height show lesser than which I defined (almost 2 to 3 pixels)` ? does this mean your cell height ? if so, delegate methods should be used

Comment: All table view you are using on the same or different-2 view controllers.

Comment: Different View Controller!

Comment: @aug2uag Cell Height, delegate already using for defining row height.